# C# web api post image as form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, form-data, image-upload

In postman it is easily done:

[image: postman-using form-data image upload]

In order to implement it by web api, i've written below code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://upload.*******.com/api/upload/photos";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

byte[] data;
using (var br = new BinaryReader(inputPhotoUpload.files.OpenReadStream()))
data = br.ReadBytes((int) inputPhotoUpload.files.OpenReadStream().Length);

ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);

MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormDataContent = new 
MultipartFormDataContent();
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(inputPhotoUpload.watermark.ToString()), "watermark");
multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent("listing"), "type");
multipartFormDataContent.Add(bytes, "files", inputPhotoUpload.files.FileName);

HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(url, multipartFormDataContent);
```

my InputPhotoUpload class

```
public class InputPhotoUpload
{
    public string watermark { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public IFormFile files { get; set; }
}
```

The uploading server accepts and image in byte array and two other values named `listing` and `watermark`. the server gives code 500 internal error.
My goal is to post a form-data post to upload an image, post man is able to do it yet my controller api cannot.

Comment: You are setting the "accept" Header to multipart/form-data. Do you really want to get form-data back from the API? I think you want to set the "Content-Type"-Header to the said value. Otherwise, compare the Headers generated by Postman to your request and make sure it is identical.

Comment: @blackforest-tom Thanks for the reply. how can i see what kind of request this api is posting? i mean fiddler cant catch the traffic so that i be able to see the exact sent headers...is there any other way to observe headers made by api request?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question after that comment. What do you mean by "headers made by api request"? Usually, Postman displays the full request. In your code, you can also see all the headers that you have set. What I meant was to look at the request in Postman, and try to replicate it with your code. If it is an open API, please post instructions to connect to it, so we can try ourselves. Oh, and did you try replacing the Accept-Header with the ContentType-Header as I mentioned?

Comment: Thank you so much, your reply helped me and i posted the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently i needed to sync all headers with postman, some were unnecessary.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();         

                ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(imageStream);
                form.Add(bytes, "files", imageName);
                form.Add(new StringContent("En"), "watermark");
                form.Add(new StringContent("listing"), "type");


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://upload.*****.com/api/upload/photos", form);
                var k = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                _Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Output>>(k);
```

Comment: it throws a 415 error code for me. Have you had any experience with it?